# How can i animate data fetched from API in my ScrollView/LazyVGrid?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, swiftui-animation

This is my main view where i'm using AsyncAwait to fetch the data. I wanna have the effect of nice animation when i receive the data. Tried a lot of things, but none worked. Some animations were successful but only after opening the specific view for the 3-rd + time. On first opening i could never achieve that effect. Would really appreciate if someone could tell me what should i do. Thanks in advance :)

```
struct PresentationRootView: View {
    // setting up the default value for segmented control
    @State private var selectedSegmentedOption: SegmentedSelection = .myPresentations
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PresentationsViewModel

    var body: some View {
        let columns =  [GridItem(.flexible())]

        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Picker(selection: $selectedSegmentedOption) {
                Text("My Presentations").tag(SegmentedSelection.myPresentations)
                Text("Templates").tag(SegmentedSelection.templates)
            } label: {}
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        }
        ScrollView {
            if selectedSegmentedOption == .myPresentations {
                if viewModel.shouldShowEmptyScreen {
                    Text("No data")
                }

                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 4, content: {
                    ForEach($viewModel.myPresentations, id: \.ID) { element in
                        PresentationSingleView(url: element.ThumbURLWithSas.wrappedValue, title: element.Name.wrappedValue, numberOfResources: 4)
                            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 13)
                    }
                }).task {
                    await viewModel.getAllPresentations(page: 1, pageSize: 10)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(CustomColor.background.swiftUIColor)
        Spacer()
        .navigationTitle("Presentations")
    }
}
```

```
struct PresentationSingleView: View {
    // replace this with the real data
    var url: URL
    var title: String
    var numberOfResources: Int
    var isIphone = DefaultAppManager.shared.isIphone
    @StateObject var image = FetchImage()


    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {

                image.view?
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(maxWidth: isIphone ? 90 : 140, maxHeight: isIphone ? 64 : 140)
                    .cornerRadius(4)

                    .padding(isIphone ? 10 : 20)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(title)
                    .font(Font.custom("Roboto-Regular", size: 12))
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                Spacer()
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Image("presentationResourceIcon")
                    Text("\(numberOfResources) resources")
                        .font(Font.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 12))
                    Spacer()
                    Image("more_options")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("tapped on right image!!!")
                        }

                }
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            }
            Spacer()
        }

        .onAppear {
            image.priority = .normal
            image.load(url)
        }

        .frame(height: isIphone ? 90 : 150)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't showing your view model, but at the least, you need to wrap your data mutations in `withAnimation`

Comment: @jnpdx thanks for the reply. I figured out it's related to image caching. :)